# Macro for Accessing Hidden Hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that enables the user to **double-click** a given cell range on a **`Summary`** worksheet and access a **hidden `Data` worksheet** containing related data.  When the user returns to the **`Summary`** worksheet, the **`Data`** worksheet is re-hidden.

The macro works perfectly for range **`D10:G15`**, but **doesn't work for cell range `C21:G26`**.

### **`Summary`** worksheet:

[image: screenshot of table]

### VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> "Group Scorecard_Usage" Then
            sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$D$10"
            Sheets("John C - Total Applicants").Visible = True
            Sheets("John C - Total Applicants").Activate
        Case "$D$11"
            Sheets("Doug D - Total Applicants").Visible = True
            Sheets("Doug D - Total Applicants").Activate
        Case "$D$12"
            Sheets("Lesia - Total Applicants").Visible = True
            Sheets("Lesia - Total Applicants").Activate
        Case "$D$13"
            Sheets("Jim Elder - Total Applicants").Visible = True
            Sheets("Jim Elder - Total Applicants").Activate
        Case "$D$14"
            Sheets("Kevin Byrnes - Total Applicants").Visible = True
            Sheets("Kevin Byrnes - Total Applicants").Activate
        Case "$D$15"
            Sheets("Chelsea W - Total Applicants").Visible = True
            Sheets("Chelsea W - Total Applicants").Activate
        Case "$E$10"
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Scott").Visible = True
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Scott").Activate
        Case "$E$11"
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Doug").Visible = True
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Doug").Activate
        Case "$E$12"
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Lesia").Visible = True
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Lesia").Activate
        Case "$E$13"
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Jim Elder").Visible = True
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Jim Elder").Activate
        Case "$E$14"
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Mark").Visible = True
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Mark").Activate
        Case "$E$15"
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Chelsea").Visible = True
            Sheets("Total_Candidates_Chelsea").Activate
        Case "$G$10"
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Scott Z").Visible = True
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Scott Z").Activate
        Case "$G$11"
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Doug").Visible = True
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Doug").Activate
        Case "$G$12"
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Lesia O").Visible = True
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Lesia O").Activate
        Case "$G$13"
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Jim").Visible = True
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Jim").Activate
        Case "$G$14"
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Mark").Visible = True
            Sheets("Unreviewed Applicants - Mark").Activate
        Case "$C$21”"
            Sheets("Scott_Hires_wo_ps").Visible = True
            Sheets("Scott_Hires_wo_ps").Activate
        Case "$C$22”"
            Sheets("Doug_Hires_wo_ps").Visible = True
            Sheets("Doug_Hires_wo_ps").Activate
        Case "$C$23”"
            Sheets("Lesia_Hires_wo_ps").Visible = True
            Sheets("Lesia_Hires_wo_ps").Activate
        Case "$C$24”"
            Sheets("Jim_Hires_wo_ps").Visible = True
            Sheets("Jim_Hires_wo_ps").Activate
        Case "$C$25”"
            Sheets("Mark_Hires_wo_ps").Visible = True
            Sheets("Mark_Hires_wo_ps").Activate
        Case "$C$26”"
            Sheets("Chelsea_Hires_wo_ps").Visible = True
            Sheets("Chelsea_Hires_wo_ps").Activate
        Case "$D$21”"
            Sheets("Scott_non_scheduled_inpersons").Visible = True
            Sheets("Scott_non_scheduled_inpersons").Activate
        Case "$D$22”"
            Sheets("Doug_non_scheduled_inperson").Visible = True
            Sheets("Doug_non_scheduled_inperson").Activate
        Case "$D$23”"
            Sheets("Lesia_non_scheduled_inpersons").Visible = True
            Sheets("Lesia_non_scheduled_inpersons").Activate
        Case "$D$24”"
            Sheets("Jim_non_scheduled_inperson").Visible = True
            Sheets("Jim_non_scheduled_inperson").Activate
        Case "$D$25”"
            Sheets("Mark_non_scheduled_inpersons").Visible = True
            Sheets("Mark_non_scheduled_inpersons").Activate
        Case "$D$26”"
            Sheets("Chelsea_ns_inpersons").Visible = True
            Sheets("Chelsea_ns_inpersons").Activate
        Case "$E$21”"
            Sheets("Scott_nc_inpersons").Visible = True
            Sheets("Scott_nc_inpersons").Activate
        Case "$E$23”"
            Sheets("Lesia_nc_inpersons").Visible = True
            Sheets("Lesia_nc_inpersons").Activate
        Case "$E$26”"
            Sheets("Chelsea_nc_inpersons").Visible = True
            Sheets("Chelsea_nc_inpersons").Activate
        Case "$F$22”"
            Sheets("Doug_Reference_Checks").Visible = True
            Sheets("Doug_Reference_Checks").Activate
        Case "$F$23”"
            Sheets("Lesia_Reference_Checks").Visible = True
            Sheets("Lesia_Reference_Checks").Activate
        Case "$F$24”"
            Sheets("Jim_Elder_Reference_Checks").Visible = True
            Sheets("Jim_Elder_Reference_Checks").Activate
        Case "$F$25”"
            Sheets("Mark_Reference_Checks").Visible = True
            Sheets("Mark_Reference_Checks").Activate
        Case "$F$26”"
            Sheets("Chelsea_Reference_Checks").Visible = True
            Sheets("Chelsea_Reference_Checks").Activate
        Case "$G$23”"
            Sheets("Lesia_BGCs").Visible = True
            Sheets("Lesia_BGCs").Activate
        Case "$G$25”"
            Sheets("Mark_BGCs").Visible = True
            Sheets("Mark_BGCs").Activate
        Case "$G$26”"
            Sheets("Chelsea_BGCs").Visible = True
            Sheets("Chelsea_BGCs").Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

I'm trying to get a handle on what I'm doing incorrectly. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Look closely at Case "$C$21”. It should be Case "$C$21". It seems you have a copy/paste error there, in other lines as well.

Comment: Tip: Please take a moment to format (indent) your code - especially long code as here - with indents so it can be scanned easily.

Comment: Why is `Case "$D$10"` "John", but the rest of the row 10 references are all "Scott"?  Plus, if you make the Hidden Sheet names more consistent, and have the person name in Column A or something, then you just need to know which name is on that row, which column you are in, and which Table you are in (via `Intersect`) to create the sheet name string, reducing your code *massively*

Answer (score 0):

You should *never, ever* have to write different lines of code for each bit of data you might get.  This is the opposite of the *purpose* of coding.

- I suspect there's relevant data in columns A & B that you haven't included... like perhaps, the person's *name*, in column `A` perhaps? If not, do that (insert a column if necessary).  Pick a naming convention and stick with it.  (ie., hyphens, underscores or spaces, not a combination) You'll save yourself (and others) a lot of headaches.
- Avoid super-long sheet names.  They're hidden anyway so you can make them simpler and more standard.  Perhaps:  `APP, CAN, UNR, WOP, NSI, NCI, REF, BGC`.
- Why do all these sheets need to be hidden?  It's not preventing people from accessing them.  Perhaps it's because there's just too darn many of them that it's cluttered?  Instead of hiding/showing them constantly you might as well **hide all the tabs** with:

  `ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False`

After these changes, you could replace almost all your code with a couple lines similar to:

```
personName = cells(Target.Row,1)
Sheets(personname & "NSI")
```

---

I bet there are *hours* spent on maintaining this workbook every week.  If this data is at all important, what you *really* should do is revamp is=t completely.

Ideally, you would move it to Microsoft Access since it's made for managing databases (as opposed to creating your own database in Excel).  Even if you've never used Access, you'd still find it simpler than what you're doing here.

Short of that, at the very least: **put all of this data on one tab**.  Excel has numerous *simple to use* features for filter and analyzing data that are useless when you split up the data like this. Keep it all together and make Excel do the work of display what you want, when you want. *You're attempting to create functionality from scratch,* that Microsoft perfected for you a long time ago.  **AutoFilter**, **Grouping**, **Pivot Tables** could all save you *so much time* and make this workbook easier for everyone else to use.

It would be a good idea to learn Excel's built-in worksheet functionality inside and out before trying to get into VBA.  There are a ton of great (free/easy) resources and forums out there that could help you, and I guarantee you'd be glad you did.

One indication that you *might* be getting ahead of yourself, happens to also be the solution **your actual question**..

> "...works perfectly fine for range `D10:G15`, but doesn't work for cell range `C21:G26`..."

## Details Matter.

So, you know something changes between `G15` and `C21`.  It makes sense to inspect that part of the code closely.

First off, **there is no `G15`** -- but besides that, if we look closely:

[image: pic2]

...looking *even* closer:

[image: pic3]

Beginning there, until the end of your code, you somehow switched to the wrong type of quotation mark on half of your functions.

**Final couple tips that will help prevent problems like this:**

1. Put, as the first line of every module: `Option Explicit`.  This will force you to properly declare and handle variables, properties, and more.
2. Before making changes, BACKUP.  If you're making 10 major changes in a day, you should keep all 10 versions, for at least a few weeks.  You'd be surprised how handy they come in, especially while learning.
3. Test your code after every change you make.  It might seem time consuming, but this is an example of how it would have saved time in the long run.

I hope didn't sound like I'm insulting you or your work, and it's *definitely* not my intention to discourage you from learning, but it is very important to be 100% thorough, accurate and organized in this field, and to understand a skill completely before moving on to the next one, especially in the earlier stages.  Be sure to check out some of the other great Excel forums out there too.  Good luck!

---

### Edit: *Example solution*

This is an example of what a difference some **basic organization** would make.  The code below has the same functionality of all of the code in the question (except this one's bug free, error handling, and automatically adaptable to new names/reports).

**Required Assumptions/Organization:**

- `Column A` contains the the manager name (worksheet name suffix): `FirstName LastInitial` ex. `Jim E` is in `A13` *and* `A24`
- `Rows 9 & 20` are *hidden* and contain the "report code" (worksheet name prefix) : ex. `D9 = TotApp` & `G20 = RefChk`
- Worksheets are renamed accordingly (ex: `TotApp Jim E`, `RefChk Jim E`)

  **Therefore we have simple logic:**

  - worksheet prefix is always column A of the clicked row.
  - if row is between 10-15 then row 9 of clicked column contains suffix.
  - if row is between 21-26 then row 20 of clicked column contains suffix.
  - therefore, the entire clickable range is C10:G15 and C21:G26

*Code:*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim destSht As String

    'make sure double-clicked cell is within range
    If Application.Intersect(Range("C10:G26"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True 'cancel the double-click
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'find the worksheet name suffix
    Select Case Target.Row
        Case 10 - 15
            destsht = Cells(9, Target.Column)
        Case 21 - 26
            destsht = Cells(20, Target.Column)
        Case Else
            Cancel = True 'cancel the double-click
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    'find the worksheet name prefix
    destsht = Cells(Target.Row, 1) & destsht

    'Unhide & activate worksheet
    With Worksheets(destsht)
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

Length: 700 char *(compared to 4700 char)*  (<sup>1</sup>/<sub>7</sub><sup>th</sup> the size of the original)